# Why do I get Slower Frame Rate while Capturing Screen in OSX?

Tags: xcode, macos, avfoundation, avcapturesession, screen-recording

I am referring to the [AVScreenShack](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/AVScreenShack/Introduction/Intro.html) example.I even got rid of the Preview feature to see if it improves. But, the Frame Skipping is very visible. I thought my computer is not powerful enough, but when I used QuickTime Player to record the Screen, the Video was silky smooth.

How can I improve the following code to get a high fps output?

```
func startRecording(){
        mSession = AVCaptureSession()
        mSession?.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh
        let displayId : CGDirectDisplayID = CGMainDisplayID()

        let session : AVCaptureSession
        if mSession != nil {
            session = mSession!
        }else{
            return
        }

        let input : AVCaptureScreenInput = AVCaptureScreenInput(displayID: displayId)
        input.minFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 35)
        if let rect = delegate?.cropRect() {
            input.cropRect = rect
        }

        if session.canAddInput(input) {
            session.addInput(input)
        }else{
            return
        }

        mMovieFileOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()

        if session.canAddOutput(mMovieFileOutput) {
            session.addOutput(mMovieFileOutput!)
        }

        mSession?.startRunning()
        mMovieFileOutput?.movieFragmentInterval = kCMTimeInvalid
        mMovieFileOutput?.startRecording(toOutputFileURL: URL(fileURLWithPath:"/Users/Tester/Desktop/capture.mov"), recordingDelegate: self)

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a higher framerate by lowering the minimum frame duration:

```
input.minFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 60)
```

N.B. this doesn't guarantee a higher framerate, but it allows one.

Comment: It is smoother than before, but still jittery. The only thing I don't understand is, human eye can detect skipping frames only if fps goes below 24. Not sure what is happening here.

Comment: Bavan - just FYI, that's out dated (I remember hearing that when I was a kid).  This source says the average population can detect 45 FPS, 25% who can see more than 60FPS and some (trained fighter pilots) who can detect over 220FPS https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/1vy3qe/how_many_frames_per_second_can_the_eye_see/?st=iqbi33ce&sh=ea892b27 Some users, you may be one, will detect skipping frames at 60FPS.